# How to pass information with a get properly in java

Tags: java

I new to java, still trying to get down arguments and passing info. I am writing a blood pressure program for school and have some issue passing info from one class to another.

I have a fully functioning system to take in the user info in one class and have to set up another to check if the average is above or below range. Now, the range is easy, but the passing of info is another thing.

So, here's the code i wrote. the ONLY thing I'm worried about is the very last part, the 'getSystolic' and its return. I need to send the info to another part of the program not in main or in this PressueInput (its BPChecker btw) and just banging my head against the problem.

### Thank you for the input:

`    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class PressureInput 
{
private int sysInput;
private int diaInput;
private int sysAvrg;
private int diaAvrg;



public PressureInput()
{               
    sysInput = 0;
    diaInput = 0;
    sysAvrg = 0;
    diaAvrg = 0;

}

public void setSysPressure()
{
    sysInput = 0;
    while(sysInput <= 0 || sysInput >= 320)
    {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter a systolic reading> ");

        sysInput= cin.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You have entered " + sysInput + "\n");

        if(sysInput <=0 || sysInput >= 320)
        {
            System.out.println("You're either dead or entered" 
                               + " an error. Try again." + "\n");
        }
    }
    sysAvrg += sysInput;
}



public int getSysPressure()
{
    return sysInput;
}




public void setDiaPressure()
{
    diaInput = 0;
    while(diaInput <= 0 || diaInput >= 320)
    {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please enter a systolic reading> ");

        diaInput= cin.nextInt();

        System.out.println("You have entered " + diaInput + "\n");

        if(diaInput <=0 || diaInput >= 320)
        {
            System.out.println("You're either dead or entered" 
                               + " an error. Try again." + "\n");
        }
    }
    diaAvrg += diaAvrg;
}


public int getDiaPressure()
{
    return diaInput;
}


public void sysAvrgRead()
{
    sysAvrg = sysAvrg / 3;
    System.out.println("\n" + "The systolic averge is " + sysAvrg);
}


public void diaAvrgRead()
{
    diaAvrg = diaAvrg / 3;
    System.out.println("The diastolic averge is " + diaAvrg + "\n");
}


public void setSystolic(int sys)
{
    sysAvrg = sys;
}


public int getSystolic()
{
    return sys;
}  
} `
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set and get with arguments in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058599/set-and-get-with-arguments-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a funftion in the class, that exhibits the var, then it should be fine. You need to make PressureInput a object, with `PressureInput varnamePI = new PressureInput();`

Then, access the var through `varnamePI.sysAvrg=0;` or so...